# GORM doesn't return the correct record based on primary key

Tags: postgresql, go, crud

I'm new to GO and I was migrating my CRUD app from using plain SQL to GORM then I ran into issues where the query based on primary key would return the primary key and nil when it matched source, whereas it should return the value/record itself as documented in: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-with-primary-key

I was expecting the value of the query

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1;
 id | name | age |         created_at         | updated_at | deleted_at | location
----+------+-----+----------------------------+------------+------------+----------
  1 | Rick |  22 | 2020-09-12 11:34:14.366674 |            |            | Toronto
(1 row)
```

Instead, I got this

```
&{0xc0000c0900 <nil> 1 0xc00009f860 0}
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go-postgres/models"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type user models.User

func main() {
    var u user
    db := loadDbSecret()
    result := db.First(&u, 1)

    fmt.Println(result)

}

func loadDbSecret() *gorm.DB {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file")
    }

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(os.Getenv("POSTGRES_URL")), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return db
}
```

THANKS!

Comment: Try printing `u` instead of `result` which is just the same instance as `db` I believe, intended to support method chaining. The return types are well documented in on [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-gorm/gorm?tab=doc#DB.First), make sure to take a look at it whenever you encounter an issue.

Comment: Try `fmt.Printf("user: %v\n", u)` instead of printing the `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You may read the [godoc](https://godoc.org) about [DB.First](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.First):

[image: Screencap of DB.First documentation on godoc]

Notice 2 thing:

1. The first parameter `out` is indeed for you to output the query result.
2. The returning value is the database instance `*DB`, not actually the query result.

You can also read the official site about [Query](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html):

> ### Retrieving a single object
>
> GORM provides First, Take, Last method to retrieve a single object from the database, it adds LIMIT 1 condition when querying the database, and it will return error ErrRecordNotFound if no record found.
>
> ```golang
> // Get the first record ordered by primary key
> db.First(&user)
> // SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
>
> // Get one record, no specified order
> db.Take(&user)
> // SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;
>
> // Get last record, order by primary key desc
> db.Last(&user)
> // SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
>
> result := db.First(&user)
> result.RowsAffected // returns found records count
> result.Error        // returns error
>
> // check error ErrRecordNotFound
> errors.Is(result.Error, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound)
> ```

In short, you should obtain your result from your variable `u` instead of `result`.

```golang
func main() {
    var u user
    db := loadDbSecret()
    result := db.First(&u, 1)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", u)
}
```

Comment: If not necessary try to avoid images, especially [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) which is easier to copy & paste for you, and, more importantly, easily understood by any interested program, e.g. search engines, blind people's screen readers, etc.

Comment: I do have link to the original text. But I have problem reproducing the original text here. The image is for better visual here. Should not have been a problem for people that needs screen reader. Besides the alt-text should be enough in explaining the image.

Comment: Right, but how would you retrieve the record using the library without result? I'm trying to extract what would be the record of the user in a type user struct which is defined under my package models?

Sorry newbie question

Comment: It's also in the official example. You can check the `result.RowsAffected` field to see if you have any result. Or you may simply check if the `user` object is filled (e.g. probably the `id` field would be 0).